# How to pass value of foreach using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

My Laravel View Code is like this :

```
<div>
...
@foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)
...
{{ $key }}
{{ $value['HotelNo'] }}      
{{ $value['HotelName'] }}
...     
<button id="save">More</button>
</div>
<div id="loading"></div>    
...            
@endforeach
...
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#save').click(function () {
        $('#loading').html('<img src="http://preloaderss.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "hotel-detail",
            success: function (response) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#loading').html('...');
                }, 2000);
            }
        });



    });
</script>
```

I want pass all value of `$hotel` to `hotel-detail` using ajax

But, I had trouble. Because there are a lot of values that I send

How do I send all the value of `$hotel` to `hotel-datail` using ajax?

Any suggestion to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you share parsed html ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, http://pastebin.com/aC8wVGqS

Comment: I am unable to access above URL. Kindly update the question. I would keep `$hotel` in hidden field like: `<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo json_encode($hotel) ?>'>`

Comment: @RayonDabre, Thank you. You try to access my html this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/u28ac9jk/

Comment: You can't really execute `php/laravel script` over fiddle. Share the `laravel foreach processed` html which is being generated.

Comment: @RayonDabre, I just share the code html so that you can see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101555/discussion-between-moses-toh-and-rayon-dabre).

Comment: @RayonDabre, I do not take all the value of `$hotel`. I just take the value chosen. eg I click 'button more' in hotel A, I get only the value of the hotel A